# MUI : How to horizontally center Grid container that has maxWidth?

Tags: material-ui

I have a grid container, inside it 2 Grid items, the Grid container has maxWidth={theme.spacing(127}, so due to the max width, the component isn't centered anymore.
My manager has told me not to use `margin: 0 auto` and i have done some research and i found it's not considered best practice to wrap the `Grid container` with a `Box`.

So is there any other ways? or maybe in this case i should implement the component in another way without Grid container?

**The component is at the bottom in the image, with gray background**

```
    <Grid container justifyContent="space-between" alignItems="center" maxWidth={theme.spacing(127)}>
      <Grid item display="flex" gap={theme.spacing(2)}>
        <Box
          display="flex"
          justifyContent="center"
          alignItems="center"
          sx={{
            borderRadius: '50%',
            maxWidth: theme.spacing(7.5),
            minWidth: theme.spacing(7.5),
            maxHeight: theme.spacing(7.5),
            minHeight: theme.spacing(7.5),
            backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
          }}>
          <EmailOutlined sx={{ color: theme.palette.white.main, fontSize: theme.spacing(4.2) }} />
        </Box>
        <Box display="flex" flexDirection="column" gap={theme.spacing(1)}>
          <Typography variant="h5" fontWeight={500}>
            {translate('stillHaveQuestions')}
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="subtitle2">{translate('cantFindAnswer')}</Typography>
        </Box>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        <a href="mailto:info@sayma.sa" style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
          <Button variant="contained" size="small">
            {translate('getInTouchButton')}
          </Button>
        </a>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

[image: The component is the one at the bottom with a gray background color]